# SQLCipher for iOS, running on armv7s and armv devices

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, sqlcipher

So I've had some headaches today trying to solve this one. I have SQLCipher integrated into an iOS application and before I go further, here are my architecture build settings:

[image: Build settings]

As I understand it, this should only build for an armv7s device (such as a iPhone 5), and when trying to run on a armv7 device I quite rightly get this error:

[image: Err]

So I try changing the project's build architecture to Standard (armv7s, armv7) and build. This still runs as expected on the armv7s device, but on a armv7 device I get these linking errors:

[image: build errors]

So naturally I check out the build settings for the library throwing these errors, and they both have armv7 and armv7s in the valid architecture setting, so does anyone know why am I getting those build errors on the armv7 device? I am missing something?

Here are the build settings for the libraries I'm using (openssl-xcode and sqlcipher):

[image: openssl xcode]
[image: sqlcipher]

Comment: Can you try setting the Architectures setting on the top level project to "armv7 armv7s" for your device builds? If that does not work, can you post the full build log to a gist.github.com?

Comment: Hey, I just fixed this. The valid architectures was not set in the sqlcipher project I got from github and once I had this set to "armv7 armv7s", I then realised how the project build process worked! I think in my testing I was sometimes not rebuilding. Anyway, a project clean and rebuild sorted it out. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenLombardo should I have build active architecture only set to NO? I have done this in openssl-xcode and sqlcipher but not in my project and all seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this read the comments above from Stephen and then I did a project clean and rebuilt it.